# How to install .apk file in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, adb, apk

I am new to android studio (1.5.1) and would like to open an `*.APK` extension file. Please tell me steps to open the file in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Android application package (APK) is the package file format used by the Android operating system for distribution and installation of mobile apps and middleware.
[Android application package format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package)

You cannot open it in Android Studio. APK is what you will get as end result when you develop applications for Android. It is binary file, not source file you can modify at will.

Answer (score 0):

In You Path get APK file in **D\ProjectPath**\app\build\outputs\apk

app-debug.apk file is Your APK file path to get

Answer (score 0):

You will get apk file from here directly[image]

If you want to build sign apk then select menu Build->Generate Signed Apk

Comment: I want to test the application i got apk file to test i folloed your instruction but my app.apk file dose not expanding.What to do

Comment: You want to decompile that apk